# background-color not visible when set

Tags: css

Would like to apply a `background-color` to a `div` that's nested inside a `footer`. The `footer` has a `background-image` covering the entire footer I set in `CSS`. The `background-color` of the `div` containing the `img`should reach the bottom of the `footer`'s `bakground-img`. Here's an illustration of what I mean:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
  <footer>
    <div class="some class">
      <img src="img/some-image.png" alt=" ">
      <div class="some class"> other content </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-footer">  </div>
  </footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
  background-image: url('../img/footer.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.some.class {
  width: 300px;
  height: 365px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background-color: (0,0,0,.97);
  z-index: 1;
}
 div.some img {
  width: 260px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 30px;
 }
```

The `img` shows but i cannot see the `background-color` of the div that has the `img`. Probably a simple fix but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `rgba`.

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.97);
```

Comment: @web-dev if your problems is solved you should accept the answer of Tania to encourage her help the people better. :-)

Comment: Sorry. I upvoted her answer so I thought that was the way to accept her answer. Is there something else I need to do to show that it was helpful?

Comment: Click the check mark that appears by the upvotes/downvotes. This way the question appears as answered to all users.